# Server side and Client side broswer width and bootstrap carousel issue in php

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out a way to do this using both server and client (or maybe just client?) side code based on the browser width. What I want to do is take a carousel from bootstrap and populate the slide portion with images from the server.

This is easy to do when the browser is of one size, its a simple sql query and a loop.

But now imagine you can have an image for 1024+, and image for 768, an image for 480px and finally an image for 320px (these are all the same image, just at different widths). How would I use php and css to create a carouse that loads one image for 1024+, then once you get down to 768px it swaps that image out for one of an appropriate size, same for 480 and 320.

I haven't tried anything other then storing the images, because to be honest I am not even sure how to approach this.

How would you accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be an option to use media queries in CSS? Although *content: url(...)*  for dynamic images aren't supported in all browsers you can play with *background url()* property of a div.

To give you an impression:

```
@media (max-width: 320px) { 
#slide1, #slide2, #slide3 {
  background:url("http://lorempixel.com/512/256");

}
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
#slide1, #slide2, #slide3 {
    background:url("http://lorempixel.com/1024/750");
}    
}
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
#slide1, #slide2, #slide3 {
  background:url("http://lorempixel.com/1920/1025");
}    
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9yh16tnn/1/) in action with a fullscreen bootstrap carousell

Comment: see this is what I was thinking but the user can switch out the slides. So if they have slide A, with an image for 1024, 768, 480 and 320 and switch it out for Slide B with its image of 1024, 768, 480 and 320 the css would have to be dynamic. plus they could have 50 or 10 slides. see the dilema?

Comment: But there is no problem in creating dynamic css. on the one hand you can easily deploy a *<link type="text/css"> ... </link>* within your HTML/PHP. With Javascript you can even apply rules dynamically during runtime ... but I guess this won't be necessary in your case